# Example how to use clp-java

Tags: java, android, optimization, linear-programming

I want to build a new linear programming model in my android app, using [cpl-java](https://quantego.github.io/clp-java/).

my function is E+T+U+URam, and i want to minimize this function, but i don't know how to use this library and how to add my constraints,
my constraints :

```
E<0 and T<0 and U<0.25 and URam<0.25
```

This is my code

```
com.quantego.clp.CLP model = new CLP();

    CLPVariable energy = model.addVariable().free();
    CLPVariable executionTime = model.addVariable().free();
    CLPVariable cpuUsage = model.addVariable().free();
    CLPVariable ramUsage = model.addVariable().free();

    CLPExpression expression = model.createExpression().add(energy).add(executionTime).add(cpuUsage)
            .add(ramUsage);

    System.out.println("expression : " + expression.toString());
    TreeMap<CLPVariable, Double> energyMap = new TreeMap<>();
    energyMap.put(energy, 5.1);

    TreeMap<CLPVariable, Double> exeTimeMap = new TreeMap<>();
    exeTimeMap.put(executionTime, 5.0);

    TreeMap<CLPVariable, Double> cpuusageMap = new TreeMap<>();
    cpuusageMap.put(cpuUsage, 0.2);

    TreeMap<CLPVariable, Double> ramusageMap = new TreeMap<>();
    ramusageMap.put(ramUsage, 0.9);

    model.addConstraint(energyMap, CLPConstraint.TYPE.LEQ, 0);
    model.addConstraint(exeTimeMap, CLPConstraint.TYPE.LEQ, 0);
    model.addConstraint(cpuusageMap, CLPConstraint.TYPE.LEQ, 0.25);
    model.addConstraint(ramusageMap, CLPConstraint.TYPE.LEQ, 0.25);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I infer that you want to minimize the sum of the decision variables, E, T, U, URam, subject to variable bounds. Since there are no constraints that link these decision variables, the optimal solution is to set all variables to their lower bounds.

From the names of the variables, I guess that the lower bounds are actually zero and not negative infinity. Setting all variables to zero would then minimize E+T+U+URam, which would yield an objective value of zero. In case you want negative infinity as lower bound, the optimization problem as it is currently stated will be unbounded.

The extensive formulation in [clp-java](https://github.com/quantego/clp-java) looks like this:

```
CLP model = new CLP().verbose(1);
CLPVariable energy = model.addVariable();
CLPVariable executionTime = model.addVariable();
CLPVariable cpuUsage = model.addVariable();
CLPVariable ramUsage = model.addVariable();    
model.createExpression().add(energy,executionTime,cpuUsage,ramUsage).asObjective();
model.createExpression().add(energy).leq(0);
model.createExpression().add(executionTime).leq(0);
model.createExpression().add(cpuUsage).leq(0.25);
model.createExpression().add(ramUsage).leq(0.25);
model.minimize();
```

Does this solve your problem?